# CoffeeScript function call - parameters and brackets

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Exists such a Javascript code:

```
var re = /some_regex/g;
return re.exec(link.attr('href'))[0]
```

How to call this in CoffeeScript
In CoffeeScript there is no need in brackets for parameters but there is another call of function in param.

I've tried:

```
re = /some_regex/g
re.exec link.attr 'href' [0]   # compile error: unexpected [
re.exec (link.attr 'href')[0]  # javascript: re.exec((link.attr('href'))[0]);
re.exec (link.attr('href'))[0] # javascript: re.exec((link.attr('href'))[0]);
```

how to do this? or I should make

```
// adding new variable
temp = re.exec link.attr 'href'
temp[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space after `re.exec` is causing a problem, because it causes the CoffeeScript compiler to think that `(link.attr('href'))[0]` is the argument.

The correct way to do this is to do it exactly like in JavaScript, with no space:

```
re.exec(link.attr('href'))[0]
```

If you really badly want to use the no-parens syntax on this line, this would also work:

```
re.exec(link.attr 'href')[0]
```

(They compile to the same result)

Comment: To further clarify: As a rule, CoffeeScript's implicit parens extend to the end of the expression. So `link.attr 'href' [0]` is equivalent to `link.attr('href'([0]))`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: A small correction to my previous comment: `'href' [0]` is itself an invalid expression, since `x [y]` compiles to `x([y])` and the compiler recognizes that strings aren't functions.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be clearer if you simply parenthesized the part that absolutely needs it, and do the rest in the most CoffeeScript-like-way?

```
(re.exec link.attr 'href')[0]
```

or maybe even (if 'href' is just another attribute):

```
(re.exec link.attr.href)[0]
```

or, better, yet, to be more clear, along the lines of what you suggested originally:

```
matches = re.exec link.attr.href
matches[0] // idiomatic to re.exec: first element is matched RE
```